# Making functions available as instance methods - Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec

```
    module Example
     def a (parameter)
       #do something
     end

     def b (parameter_2)
        #do something
     end
    end

   class C
     include Example
   end
```

This is a sample Ruby code. I wish to know how to make functions a and b available to class C as instance methods. These will be tested automatically by another program.

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't functions, they are instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They already are.

```
c = C.new
c.methods - 0.methods
# => [:a, :b]
```

By virtue of including the module, you've [extended the functionality](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm) of `C` to include that of the module `Example`.

Comment: It gives me a deprecation warning in rspec though. 'Should'  being used instead of 'expect'. Is there any work around instead of replacing all should with expect?

Comment: That RSpec warning had nothing to do with what you've posted here.  In all actuality, you need to replace "should" with "expect" in your tests anyway.